# How do you get the pieces of heart on the way to Zora's Domain?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

On the way up towards Zora's Domain from the central overworld area, there's a long river with a lot of paths over it. I saw 2 pieces of heart on my way up, but couldn't figure out how to get either of them. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the chicken, but I can't figure out how to get the chicken to a useful place to glide to the pieces of heart.

How do you get these two pieces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed, the way to get them is to use the chicken.

http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d/Zora%27s_Domain

> River Heart Pieces
>
> There are two Heart Pieces to grab while en route to Zora's Domain.
>   They are attainable only with the help of the lone cucco near the
>   Magic Bean. Grab the cucco and jump to the other side of the river.
>   Walk until you hit a wall, then make a short jump across the water to
>   the left. Keep going higher by jumping across the small gap to the
>   left. Take a right after the gap and keep walking. You'll see the
>   heart piece sitting on a platform off to the right. Use the cucoo to
>   flutter you over to the high platform in front of you, but when you're
>   about to hit the ledge, toss the cucoo in order to make Link grab onto
>   the ledge and pull himself up. Then make a daring leap toward the
>   heart piece and Link will just barely latch on to the edge. Hoist him
>   up to obtain this Heart Piece.
>
> Retrieve your cucco friend. If you can't find him, exit and re-enter
>   the area; he will return to his original location. With chicken in
>   hand, work your way up along the river, watching out for Octoroks.
>   When you get to the large waterfall, walk up as high as you can and
>   look around. You should spot a Heart Piece on a ledge protruding from
>   a wall. Jump and hover to it to receive another Heart Piece.